# How to perform action KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN in Android M

Tags: android, keyevent, sendkeys

I am using Android M (Galaxy S6). I have an activity that will perform the action down (similar when we press the physical down button/volume down). Without any press the physical button, I want to perform the action by code in Android M. This is my code but it does not work. Could you help me to fix it? Note that, I do not want to use any root permission

First way:

```
 BaseInputConnection mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(findViewById(R.id.button), true);
                    KeyEvent down = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME, 0);
                    mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(down);
```

Second way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
     Integer.toString(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN));
```

Comment: do you mean hardware back button?

Comment: No. The volume down and up button by programming